# Material UI Collapsible Table - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

**I am trying to create a material UI collapsible table in react.js without using npm, but I am getting errors like the ones below.

I commented on each line and checked, and I found an error in the Row component's row property.
**

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.[missing argument]

```
let { useState, useEffect, useRef, forwardRef } = React;
const { Paper, Checkbox, Card, Box, Collapse, IconButton, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow,
    Typography, KeyboardArrowDownIcon, KeyboardArrowUpIcon } = MaterialUI;

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, price) {
    return {
        name,
        calories,
        fat,
        carbs,
        protein,
        price,
        history: [
            {
                date: '2020-01-05',
                customerId: '11091700',
                amount: 3,
            },
            {
                date: '2020-01-02',
                customerId: 'Anonymous',
                amount: 1,
            },
        ],
    };
}


const rows = [
    createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 3.99),
    createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3, 4.99),
    createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0, 3.79),
    createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3, 2.5),
    createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9, 1.5),
];

Row.propTypes = {
    row: PropTypes.shape({
        calories: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        carbs: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        fat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
                amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                customerId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
        ).isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        protein: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
};

function Row(props) {
    const { row } = props;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <TableRow sx={{ '& > *': { borderBottom: 'unset' } }}>
                <TableCell>
                    <IconButton
                        aria-label="expand row"
                        size="small"
                        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                    >
                        {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
                    </IconButton>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
                    <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                        <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
                            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                                History
                            </Typography>
                            <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                                <TableHead>
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">Total price ($)</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>
                                </TableHead>
                                <TableBody>
                                    {row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                                        <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {historyRow.date}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{historyRow.customerId}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.amount}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">
                                                {Math.round(historyRow.amount * row.price * 100) / 100}
                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    ))}
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        </Box>
                    </Collapse>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

function OnlineFareDemo() {


    return (
        <div>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell />
                            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {rows.map((row) => (
                            < Row key={row.name} row={row} />
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<OnlineFareDemo />, document.querySelector("#OnlineFareRoot"))
```